# Как отловить некоторое количество сильных сигналов в условиях шума?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, arduino

Пока не знаю правильно ли формулирую вопрос, но попробую.
Есть приёмник сигнала, например фоторезистор. Этим приёмником может быть и микрофон, не суть.

1. В условиях изменяющейся обстановки (день, ночь) уровень шумов может сильно меняться, но тем не менее нужный сигнал будет самым сильным. То есть нужно отфильтровать сильные сигналы. Но это, видимо, будет задаваться уровнями чувствительности.
2. Нужно отлавливать некоторое, заранее заданное, количество этих сигналов, но они будут приходить неравномерно. То есть одна последовательность придет с паузами 0.5, 1, 0.5 сек. А другая с 1, 1.2, 1.5 сек. Как отловить такие последовательности?

Comment: Это Вам надо почитать про ЦОС (цифровая обработка сигналов). По задаче, на пальцах, из того что понял, считаете среднюю амплитуду за какой-то период, и сравниваете с текущим сигналом, если выходит за заданный порог, считаете полезным сигналом, иначе шум.

Comment: Да, по первому я примерно так и хочу сделать. Вычислять среднее за последние N секунд и считать это фоном.

Comment: Что из себя представляет сигнал? Просто импульс?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если полезный сигнал у Вас является коротким импульсом на фоне шума, можно поступить следующим образом:

1. Удалить из выборки постоянную составляющую (не обязательно).
2. Найти `max` значение из выборки.
3. Задаться уровнем детектирования, например `detectorLevel = 0.7 * max`.
4. Пробежаться по выборке и подсчитать количество положительных перепадов `detCount` (например, 
   `(mas[i-1] <= detectorLevel) && (detectorLevel < mas[i])`).
5. Пробежаться по выборке и подсчитать количество значений `detCount`, для которых `mas[i] > detectorLevel`.
6. Проверить, были ли импульсы (`detCount > 0`) и проверить долю заполнения этими импульсами всей выборки (например, для 10% - `detCount * 10 < size`).

Comment: В п.4 можно наловить кучу шумов, тут для выделения полезного сигнала хорошо использовать петлю гистерезиса.

Comment: Согласен, именно для этого применяется п. 5 и вторая половина п. 6. Если мы знаем, что частота полезных импульсов намного меньше частоты дискретизации, так вполне можно поступить. Опять же - это частный случай, для которого есть масса "если у вас именно так".

Answer (score 0):

Если сигнал гармонический, то он всегда делится на самую нижнюю частоту и её гармоники. Поэтому определяете частоту сигнала и делаете фильтр, подавляющий все частоты, кроме заданной частоты. Отфильтрованный таким образом сигнал обрабатываете по амплитуде. Если сигнал негармонический, то нужно смотреть, какова дельта между двумя последовательными выборками с АЦП. В простейшем случае начало полезного сигнала можно будет отловить по переднему фронту. В более сложном потребуется вычислять интеграл с некоторой частотой, в разы меньшей, чем частота выборок с АЦП (в этом случае схема будет срабатывать с небольшим запаздыванием).

Answer (score 0):

Несколько основных моментов.

1. Обработка сигнала ведётся в скользящем временном окне, симметричном по отношению к сигналу. Поэтому результат будет сформирован с задержкой.
2. Шумовой тренд при наличии сильного импульсного сигнала лучше всего определять как [медиану в скользящем окне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479508/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/479612#479612) и вычитать.
3. Нужно вычислять порог путём умножения СКО полученной выборки на коэффициент 2.5, или 20 lg 2.5 = 8 дБ.
4. Сигналом считать превышение порога.