# Алгоритм поиска по шаблону

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, математика, анализ

У меня есть пара подобных сканеров разных производителей.
Задача относится к 2D (до 3D пока далеко).

При запросе данных приходит пакет (одномернвый массив) размерностью ~1000, на каждую точку, два значения первое Х второе У.

ПРИМЕР МАССИВА (вид на графике будет, линия с маленьким уклоном)

[25,354;40,250;25,599;40,942;.......... 50,304;42,231]

В первом случае необходимо найти [следующую точку](http://c2n.me/3H45i6N) (на картинке помечена синим):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но это должен быть не просто максимум из массива.
Фактически это 4 линии (из массива точек) алгоритм, должен объеденить точки в линии и уже исходя из количества найденных линий, искать что то определенное на них или в них (середина, зазор между первой и второй)

Параметры который можно менять в алгоритме это полуширина линии (расстояние от шума до расчетной линии), прежде чем алгоритм объединяет их в линии еще он просматривает максимальное расстояние от точки до точки и решает включать ее в линию или нет.

Использую метод наименьших квадратов, но работает это только с прямыми. 
и то не совсем корректно.
Как правильно объединить точки в линии и после оперировать с линиями?
Потому что мой алгоритм отрабатывает один раз из ста.

пример
[сканера по ссылке (тык в меня)](http://www.micro-epsilon.com/2D_3D/laser-scanner/model-selection/)!

Comment: Дайте просто массив данных, лучше с наиболее сложными ситуациями.

Comment: @Yuri Negometyanov
не совсем понял вас
приходит обычный одномерный массив размерностью ~1000 элементов
из них 500 значения для Х и 500 для Y
[X1,Y1,X2,Y2,X3,Y3........X500,Y500]
в секунду приходит около 500 пакетов с такими координатами

Comment: Просто откорректируйте вопрос - выложите туда массив, соответствующий картинке. Так принято делать, поскольку стороние ссылки не всегда стабильны.

Comment: @Yuri Negometyanov
исправился

Comment: Всё ли получилось?

Comment: @Yuri Negometyanov

благодарю за помощь, сейчас реализовываю шаблонную графику и некоторый необходимый срочно функционал, после приступлю к алгоритму)
Все время которое посвещал до этого, вопросу алгоритма результата не приносил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем виде алгоритм обработки должен быть таким:

1. Оценить тренд данных при помощи [фильтра скользящей медианы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479508/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/479612#479612). Обработку вести только по координате Y.
2. Вычислить разделённые разности по медианному тренду.
   Максимальные по модулю значения разделённой разности первого порядка
   **(y<sub>i+1</sub>-y<sub>i</sub>)/(x<sub>i+1</sub>-x<sub>i</sub>)**, вычисленные по тренду, указывают на точки разрыва функции.
3. Вычислить переменную составляющую (разность между исходными данными и полученным трендом). Максимумы суммы модулей этой величины по 3-5 точкам сигнализируют об изломе функции.
4. Фрагменты данных, выделенные в пп.2-3, можно приближать гладкими зависимостями (в том числе по методу наименьших квадратов). Без отделения фрагментов использование суммы квадратов вместо суммы модулей по п.3 даёт менее устойчивую статистику.

Comment: Если шаг по Х практически постоянный, то можно вычислять простые разности, а не разделённые.