# Сортировка методом вставок и слияния

Tags: алгоритм

Пытаюсь вникнуть в алгоритм, описанный в книге Дональда Кнута "Искусство программирования", но не могу понять алгоритм. В нем описана последовательность вставки элементов в основной список, не могу понять эту закономерность.  Ссылка на алгоритм [здесь](https://vk.com/doc10903696_194275326hash=a31988db0d5efa430a&dl=3c0aab6af8e0d67989) (191 страница). Может быть, кто-то поможет понять алгоритм?

Comment: Page not found.  Где это место в книге? на 191 странице издания 2000 года - упражнения.

Comment: Скажите хоть букву алгоритма (у Кнута они все обозначены буквами), а лучше вбейте описание тут. В Т.3 издания "Мир" 1978 г. на 191 стр. тоже упражнения.

Comment: Уточните суть вопроса (картинку выложите, что ли). И объясните суть проблемы так, как её видите.

Comment: Если Вас устроил ответ, поставьте галочку напротив него. Такие правила. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*19.03.17*

[В книге](https://vk.com/doc10903696_194275326?hash=a31988db0d5efa430a&dl=3c0aab6af8e0d67989) показано, что бинарная вставка оптимальна для случая вставки нового элемента в упорядоченную цепочку длиной **2<sup>k</sup>-1** элементов. Кроме того, она допускает [модернизацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479508/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/479612#479612) для рекуррентной сортировки массива в "скользящем окне". Но в промежутке между оптимальными значениями её эффективность замораживается, что даёт кусочно - линейную зависимость производительности алгоритма от количества точек.

В то же время сортировка слиянием обеспечивает равномерное и почти оптимальное время выполнения. И кстати: если к первому массиву дописать второй массив в обратном порядке, то при сортировке слиянием расстояние между сравниваемыми элементами декрементируется на каждом шаге, что создаёт удобства в реализации.

Метод вставок и слияния комбинирует преимущества двух предыдущих.

В рассматриваемом месте книги (после начальной сортировки) использованы слеующие соображения:
(7) новое число **b<sub>3</sub>** можно вставить в цепочку {**b<sub>1</sub> ≤ a<sub>2</sub> ≤ a<sub>3</sub>**} за два сравнения (первое сравнение - с **a<sub>2</sub>**);
после этого слева от **b<sub>2</sub>** окажется цепочка из трёх элементов **b<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>3</sub>**, последовательность которых мы уже знаем;
таким образом, на эту вставку потребуется тоже два сравнения;
(8) цепочка элементов **с<sub>1</sub>-a<sub>4</sub>** содержит 7 элементов, из которых **c<sub>4</sub>** - средний;
после сравнения **b<sub>4</sub>** со средним элементом становится ясно, в какую из трёхзвенных частей надо его вставлять;
(9) мы уже поняли, что:
после сравнения нового элемента со средним элементом трёхзвенной цепочки сомнения остаются только по одному элементу, и поэтому вставка в трёхзвенную цепочку требует двух сравнений;
в случае 7-звенной цепочки после первого сравнения сомнения остаются только по трёхзвенной цепочке, и потому вставка в 7-звенную цепочку требует трёх сравнений;
но в верхней цепочке ровно 15 элементов, и после сравнения "левого" элемента **b<sub>11</sub>** c центральным элементом **d<sub>8</sub>** останется одна сомнительная 7-звенная цепочка, поэтому вставка в целом требует 4 сравнений;
на моменты вставки элементов **b<sub>10</sub>**, **b<sub>9</sub>**, **b<sub>8</sub>**, **b<sub>7</sub>**, **b<sub>6</sub>** для каждого из них окажется сомнительной цепочка из 15 элементов, и поэтому каждая вставка потребует 4 сравнений.

Попробуйте написать код для сортировки 5 элементов за 7 сравнений.

Заметим, что выборку в `20` элементов можно разбить на `4` группы по `5` элементов, после чего:
1) отсортировать каждую из групп за `7` сравнений (**4 х 7 = 28**);
2) слить группы попарно (не более `9` сравнений на пару групп, всего **2 х 9 = 18** сравнений);
3) объединить полученные группы слиянием (не более **19** сравнений).
Итого: **65** сравнений на **20** элементов, при том что **log<sub>2</sub>20! = 61.1**. Т.е самый гениальный метод даст выигрыш максимум в 3 сравнения.

Рассмотренный в книге алгоритм носит сильный отпечаток искусственности (что, собственно, и является темой книги). С другой стороны, хороший запас подобных находок (как готовых алгоритмов, так и удачных приёмов) расширяет спектр возможностей алгоритмиста. Например, для `42` элементов с учётом разобранного алгоритма можно уложиться в **2 х 66 + 41 = 173** сравнения, в то время как **log<sub>2</sub> 42! = 169.9**. А можно применить только что разобранную схему из книги к **2х5+1 = 11** точкам и отсортировать их за **26** сравнений - при том, что **log<sub>2</sub>11! = 25.3**.

Следует иметь в виду, что оптимальные алгоритмы востребованы в основном при разработке спецвычислительной техники. А на практике даже библиотечные алгоритмы сортируют бинарным слиянием, а про группы из 5 и тем более 21 элементов особо не думают.

Comment: алгоритм называется "сортировка посредством  вставок и слияния" в книге "искусство программирования" ,том 3 , страница 191 https://vk.com/doc10903696_194275326?hash=a31988db0d5efa430a&dl=3c0aab6af8e0d67989

Comment: @Александр готово.

Comment: это конечно хорошо ,но мой вопрос был немного в другом если посмотреть на продолжение алгоритма(на странице 192) там идет общее описание того какой элемент сравнивать первым(очередность их вставки)вот это мне не особо понятно ,я не вижу закономерности

Comment: спасибо Yuri Negometyanov, в общем то понятно что нужно выбирать путь с наименьшим количеством сравнений, но можно ли это автоматизировать? Как я понял на странице идет обобщение ,четкая закономерность которая мне мне не понятна ,если кто-то понял можете обьяснить недалекому

Comment: @Александр первым сравнивается тот элемент, у которого сомнительная цепочка составляет 3, 7, 15, 31, 63..., т.е, 2^k-1 элементов. В этом случае вставка оптимальна.

Comment: а ведь действительно ,спасибо Yuri Negometyanov.

Comment: @Александр Приятно слышать. Но главное - чтобы помогло.